# New Line Character in Rich Text Box with InfoPath 2010

Tags: infopath, rich-text

I have a rich text box in an InfoPath 2010 form (will be used in the browser) that I want to have some default text similar to:

Text A:

Text B:

Tried a few methods around use an XML resource file that contains line feed characters, with these inserted with the concat formula, but it seems to ignore this and come out on one line.  I think people must have been doing this with just a text box and not a rich text box.

How can I do this with a rich text box? Thanks.

Comment: Have you found the answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

This post could give you an idea how this could be done programatically - http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/how-to-render-html-in-rich-text-box-infopath.htm

Comment: Unfortunately I am using a SharePoint list and not a forms library.  Therefore I cannot add code to this form.